# mysql (aws forced update) from 5.6 to 5.7 causing slower queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Premise:
I have a db (was running well on mysql 5.6) that got upgraded to 5.7 and is causing performance issues. The front end gets aroun 20k requests per minute (consistent). Each request generates an IODKU into one of the tables.

RDS hardware:
db.m5.large

On 5.6, CPU: 30%, Avg DB Connections: 20
On 5.7, CPU: 75%, Avg DB Connections: 255.

For the following query:

show global status like 'threads%';

I keep refreshing, and For the most part I can see

Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   257
Threads_created 203899
Threads_running 255

But In between, for a short bit, it will also go to

Threads_cached  30
Threads_connected   3
Threads_created 206709
Threads_running 1

I have spend around 3 days, reading, and changing different parameter group values. See below my changes, links I based my actions on,  results, etc.

=============

optimizer_switch

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193262/after-mysql-upgrade-to-5-7-optimizer-not-using-index-on-large-in-clause

https://support-acquia.force.com/s/article/360061350614-Resolving-unexpected-slow-database-queries-after-MySQL-5-7-upgrade

changes mentioned in this link did not make much difference.

=========

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174527/poor-mysql-5-7-performance-compared-to-mysql-5-6

originally set to 1. Changing to 2 did not make any difference

=======

query_cache_size

original: 1048576. Changing to 67108864 Did not make any difference.

=======

query_cache_type

shows as OFF. Changing to 1.Seemed to worsen. So put it back to OFF. Had to restart.

========

innodb_io_capacity
default: 200. Changing to 400 and even 800. Did not make any difference.

======
innodb_flush_neighbors
default: 1. changing to 0. Did not make any difference.

======

thread_cache_size

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/
default: 14. Changing to 32. Did not make any difference.

=======

tmp_table_size
default: 16777216. Changing to 33554432. Did not make any difference.

======
innodb_read_io_threads,
innodb_write_io_threads
default: 4. changing to 8. Needs reboot. Made things worse. Putting back to 4.

===========
Pretty much all links from google search on this regard are now "pink" on my browser (meaning already visited), and I am kinda at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE#1:**

Enabled Slow_query_log. Waited for a while, and this is what is in the log.

/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.7.38-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time Id Command Argument
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 5.7.38-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time Id Command Argument
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------

**UPDATE 2**

For each Request The following happens.

Query#1

SELECT m.id AS uID,m.tkn,m.email FROM memberTable m WHERE m.tkn='$subTkn'

For memberTable, id (primary) and tkn(indexed) have indexes.

Then after some processing, the following Query#2 happens.

INSERT into dataTable (memberID,status,packetTime ) VALUES ('76418','1','2022-12-25 22:10:33') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE memberID='76418',status='1',packetTime='2022-12-25 22:10:33'

For dataTable, memberID(primary) is indexed.

**UPDATE#3**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT m.id AS uID,m.tkn,m.email FROM memberTable m WHERE m.tkn='$subTkn'

id      select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
76418   SIMPLE      m       NULL        const   tkn             tkn     42      const   1       100.00      NULL    



EXPLAIN INSERT into dataTable (memberID,status,packetTime ) VALUES ('76418','1','2022-12-25 22:10:33') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE memberID='76418',status='1',packetTime='2022-12-25 22:10:33'

id  select_type table       partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   INSERT  dataTable   NULL        ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
```

**UPDATE 4**

show variables like "transact%";

```
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192    
transaction_allow_batching  OFF 
transaction_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ 
transaction_prealloc_size   4096    
transaction_read_only   OFF 
transaction_write_set_extraction    OFF
```

optimizer_switch

```
index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=off,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=off,prefer_ordering_index=on
```

Comment: My guess is that the query optimiser changed a bit and there is some query which is not using indexes anymore. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721225/query-execution-time-on-mysql-8/74723734#74723734). I'd enable slow query log to check which query causes this threads_created spike and checked indexes for it.

Comment: @DmitryC Thanks, I am enabling slow query log now. See update above.

Comment: Queries whose execution time is less than `long_query_time` won't be logged in the slow query log. Note that even if a query's lock time is longer, that doesn't count for the slow query log.

Comment: @BillKarwin ok, I understand. Anything else I can check?

Comment: You haven't shown the query that is affected by the performance difference. You mentioned that there are many IODKU queries, are those the only ones with degraded performance? Are insert to all tables affected? Are there any obvious differences in the tables affected, like any unique indexes, foreign keys, etc.?

Comment: What is the `optimizer_switch` of the prior 5.6 instance compared to that option in the new 5.7 instance? There have been cases of performance regressions due to new optimizer features, and many of the new optimizer features can be disabled optionally. You could try to change `optimizer_switch` to mimic the old 5.6 behavior. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html and study the differences.

Comment: @aVC wait for the threads_created spike with the slow_query_log enabled. Make sure that the "slow query time" parameter is configured shorter than this "short bit" moment you noticed, so queries will be logged.

Comment: While I support @Bill Karwin's approach of solving the problem in the short term, I'd look for the problematic query anyways, because mimicking the old 5.6 behaviour may cause even more problems in the long run (like missing optimisations added in 5.7)

Comment: @aVC for update 2: please add "EXPLAIN" queries for all queries you collected (execute them with the "EXPLAIN" keyword in front of them)

Comment: @DmitryC I agree with your comment. Fixing the queries so they work with the default optimizer settings of MySQL 5.7 is preferred. Changing the optimizer_switch is a good test, to narrow down the cause of the performance problem.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, I agree with you. As long as I can identify what's causing the issue, I can definitely fix any issues with the query.  Not trying to get around with parameter updates. I updated post with explain results. Seems like my question might get closed.

Comment: The queries you posted are pretty straightforward. It's hard to imagine any way optimizer changes in 5.7 could affect them. Perhaps it's due to lock conflicts instead of optimizer differences? I'd look for the slow query log to show high `lock_time` values if that's the case. Maybe changing the transaction isolation level to READ-COMMITTED could help.

Comment: I know! queries are pretty basic. slow query log shows nothing more than what I posted. No lock time or anything. Please see update4. Though I don't see an entry for read_isolation in parameter settings.

Comment: Is it possible that queries are running fine, but some thing like logging or log file size etc might be the culprit?

Comment: @aVC there are at least 2 more things we can do to check queries 1. try reducing "slow query log time" and see which queries you can catch. 2. Try to catch the "threads_created spike moment" at the same time executing "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" on the MySQL side. The 2nd one would be perfect but it's not always possible.

Comment: @DmitryC Thanks,  I checked on parameter settings, no such thing as slow_query_log_time that I can find. There is a long_query_time. It was set to 10, I tried going as low as 1, but no entries in slow uery log. Also, On processlist, nothing seems to go above 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @aVC "On processlist, nothing seems to go above 2-3 seconds." - yes, this is expected. We need to catch the moment when the threads_created skyrockets and check how many queries we have in the full processlist (and what they're waiting for, the status field). There are 3 possible options: 1. They're just executing/not waiting for anything according to the state. Try "EXPLAIN" + try [optimising the relevant table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html). 2. They're waiting for some lock/locking query. We'll need to investigate this query :). 3. no queries

Comment: Note that 5.7 is near end of life too.  Consider moving to 8 or mariadb now.

Comment: @DmitryC Got it. As for tables, I did optimize all tables. No errors were found.

Comment: @ysth Yes, actually when we got notice that 5.6 is being pushed out, we were working to move to 8 right away, but things got stalled. Now, unfortunately, we are in scramble mode. Very frustrating when something working really well, totally messes up with version upgrade, and one can't figure out. Hopefully will get to the root cause soon.

Comment: You can set `long_query_time` to 0. This means to log all slow queries that take 0 or more seconds. This is obviously all queries. You set it to 1 second, which likely misses a lot of queries.

Comment: After running the slowlog for an hour with `long_query_time` less than 1. use `pt-query-digest to summarize the slowlog.  Focus on the slowest few entries.  More on [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Does the `SELECT` have a `FOR UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

For those who reach this part of the island, here is how my issue was resolved. I had a continuous barrage of queries that were IODKU. Apparently, this is causing row locks in innoDB. Had to change the code, and query to UPDATE (unless insert is required), and all seems back to normal.

Thanks, Bill, DimitryC for asking insightful questions.

For Rick:

1. show create table dataTable

> 

```
CREATE TABLE `dataTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberID` bigint(15) NOT NULL,
  `action` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timeOfLastEvent` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeSinceLastEvent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  ....../*Few additional columns, mostly INT or DECIMAL with defaults set to 0*/..........
 
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `packetTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'UTC/GMT time when data is received',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `memberID` (`memberID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28051225912 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

2. You were doing IODKU when UPDATE was all that was needed?

> NO, My use case was that new inserts could happen, so I used IODKU. But this was very rare compared to the updates. So, I now have two separate modules, a new one to handle inserts if needed.

> Another reason that pointed towards this: If you look at my original post, you will see the IODKU that I am using. I posted the EXPLAIN as requested by Dimitry, and you can see that IODKU was not using indexes, where as update did use index. So, not really knowing if that would fix the issue, I changed to simple UPDATE, and the db load just got back to normal levels as mysql5.6 days. Now, I dont know if this is the right solution, or whether I got lucky.

3. Does the SELECT have a FOR UPDATE?

> NO, I was not using a select for update. I was blindly using IODKU, as it was working without any issues on 5.6.

4. SAMPLE IODKU code is same as in the question.

   ```
    INSERT into dataTable (memberID,status,packetTime )
          VALUES ('76418','1','2022-12-25 22:10:33')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
             memberID='76418',
             status='1',
             packetTime='2022-12-25 22:10:33'
   ```
5. UPDATED code.

   ```
    UPDATE dataTable SET
      status='1',
      packetTime='2022-12-25 22:10:33'
    where memberID='76418'`
   ```
6. When I ran "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" WITH the IODKU, I could see a lot of

   ```
    ---TRANSACTION 114650874007, ACTIVE 3 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    12 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 49055080, OS thread handle 22829943932672, query id 200466639 172.31.55.242 application update
      INSERT into dataTable (memberID,status,packetTime)
      VALUES ('10425151','1','2022-12-27 21:01:24')
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        memberID='10425151',
        status='1',
        packetTime='2022-12-25 21:01:24'
   ```

But with just UPDATE, the engine status query is much shorter, and none of the above entries.

Hope this helps, Rick.

And thanks to the two who voted to close this question. Very helpful.

Comment: Wait...  You were doing IODKU when UPDATE was all that was needed?  Or did you add a `SELECT` to see if IODKU was needed?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample of the IODKU and the code that replaced it.  This will be a big benefit to the rest of us.

Comment: @RickJames Please see udpated answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any need for `id`, or can `memberID` be the PK instead?  How many rows in the table?

Comment: @RickJames Originally we used to use this to sort, but later, many things were added organically. At this point, we could get away without the id table. Member table is 30k rows. Around 20k are active on a regular basis, and hits the db, resulting in an update.